# What does it mean when a random variable Y is equal to $2^X$ where X is a discrete random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables, entropy

I'm trying to see what is the ratio of $H(X)$ and $H(Y)$ when $Y=2^X$ .$H$ is the entropy of a random variable.

I have tried using the definition of entropy, but i don't understand what is $2^X$ to continue with this approach.

Comment: $Y = 2^X$ means that you are taking the values of the random variable $X$ and creating a new random variable $Y$ via the function. For example a uniform random variable $X$ of $\{0,1\}$ would be mapped to $Y \in \{1, 2\}$.

Comment: Also their probabilities do not change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entropy of a random variable has nothing to do with the particular values of the variable. Your variable $X$ has certain values $x_i$, which are taken with probabilities $p_i$. The random variable $Y$ then has the values $y_i=2^{x_i}$, which are taken by the same probabilities $p_i$. As $t\mapsto 2^t$ is injective it follows that
$$H(Y)=H(X)=-\sum_i p_i\>\log_2 p_i\ .$$

Comment: I see thank you. If for example $Y=cosX$ the entropy will still be the same cause the probabilities do not change ?

Comment: @user3133165: The function $\cos$ is not injective. Depending on the actual $x_i$ one may have $y_i=y_{i'}$ for some $i\ne i'$. This changes things.